# VSCode autocomplete/intellisense(?) in Jupyter Notebook when starting string literals keeps making me accidentally insert 'ArithmeticError' every time

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, jupyter

[screenshot of the popup code suggestion box being mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FTcz.png)

In VSCode Jupyter Notebook code cells, I keep having this annoying popup when I open any single or double quotes. It doesn't appear on markdown cells, nor in regular editor on .py files. It doesn't look like your typical IntelliSense suggestions either (I think), and I've tried to disable as many of such extensions as possible, but I'm not able to get rid of this annoying popup.

Appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Or at least what it's actually called, so I can Google the correct term. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out.

In VS Code settings, go to **Extensions** > **Jupyter** > **Python Completion Trigger Characters**

defaults were: `.%'"`

So I deleted the single and double quotes, restarted, and voila, no more annoying popups.

Comment: Thank you, this was annoying me to death!
I just wanted to comment to to others here that unlike with all other vscode settings I'm used to, a full restart of vscode was apparently required here. Also, for future benefit, here's the direct setting that can be added to the settings.json: `"jupyter.pythonCompletionTriggerCharacters": ".%",`